# Tips on generating Pete Frame-style Rock Family Tree in Graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz

I've written a simple python program (my first!) that takes three CSV files - people, bands, links - and generates a Graphviz DOT file that shows a "rock family tree", where people show up in different bands, and bands go through different lineups. I'm trying to get close to [Pete Frame's wonderful Rock Family Trees](https://www.google.ae/search?q=pete%20frame%20rock%20family%20trees&client=ubuntu&hs=2mf&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjErZblp6TVAhWDNJoKHaTPATsQ_AUICigB&biw=1360&bih=609) (although they'll never look that good, or that detailed).

The code generated so far looks like this:

```
digraph Family_Tree {
graph [style="solid", ranksep="0.6", fontname="Berthold Akzidenz Grotesk", fontsize=24, label="Those About to Post-Rock", labelloc="tl", bgcolor="white", fontcolor="black", penwidth="1", color="black", margin=0, nodesep="0.1", splines="polyline"];
edge [fontname="Berthold Akzidenz Grotesk", fontsize=10, arrowhead="none", penwidth="1", minlen="1" ];
node [style="solid", margin="0", fontname="Berthold Akzidenz Grotesk", shape="none", fontsize=20, fillcolor="white"  ];


# band members - unique per person/band combination

"(various people) - Eviva" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">(various people)</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">drums, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"(various people) - The Attic" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">(various people)</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">drums, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"ABB - Zirkus" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">ABB</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">synths, machines, programming</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Adam Clayton - Flange Circus #2" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Adam Clayton</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">keyboard, violin</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Bon Holloway - Chameleon Day" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Bon Holloway</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Bon Holloway - Flange Circus #1" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Bon Holloway</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar, keyboard, programming, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Bon Holloway - Flange Circus #2" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Bon Holloway</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar, keyboard, programming, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Bon Holloway - Nocturne" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Bon Holloway</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Bon Holloway - Rose Garden Sacrifice" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Bon Holloway</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Charles Freedman - Eviva" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Charles Freedman</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Chris Gunningham - Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Chris Gunningham</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">bass</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Chris Jones - Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Chris Jones</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">drums</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Craig McIntosh - Wooly Mammoth" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Craig McIntosh</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Danny Tompkins - Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Danny Tompkins</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Darren Hanson - Chameleon Day" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Darren Hanson</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">bass</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Darren Hanson - Nocturne" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Darren Hanson</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">bass</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Darren Hanson - Rose Garden Sacrifice" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Darren Hanson</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">bass</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Dave Colbourne - Terminal Sunshine" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Dave Colbourne</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">drums</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Glenn ??? - The Attic" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Glenn ???</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Glenn ??? - The Yahoo's" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Glenn ???</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Jamie Wire - Eviva" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Jamie Wire</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">bass, guitar</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Jay Stillwell - Chameleon Day" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Jay Stillwell</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">drums</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Jay Stillwell - Nocturne" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Jay Stillwell</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">drums</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Jay Stillwell - Rose Garden Sacrifice" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Jay Stillwell</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">drums</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"John Taylor - Flange Circus #1" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">John Taylor</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">organ</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"John Taylor - Flange Circus #2" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">John Taylor</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">organ</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Josh Saunders - Nocturne" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Josh Saunders</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Josh Saunders - Rose Garden Sacrifice" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Josh Saunders</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Martin Smith - A4 Notice" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Martin Smith</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">synths, programming</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Matthew Eades - Wooly Mammoth" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Matthew Eades</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">bass, guitar, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Matthew Petty - Probe" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Matthew Petty</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">machines</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Nick Topp - Plunge" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Nick Topp</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">drums</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Paul Morgan - Plunge" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Paul Morgan</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Paul Stevenson - Terminal Sunshine" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Paul Stevenson</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Pete Collins - A4 Notice" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Pete Collins</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">synths, bass, programming</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Pete Collins - Eviva" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Pete Collins</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">keyboards, programming</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Pete Collins - Flange Circus #1" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Pete Collins</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">bass, keyboard, programming</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Pete Collins - Flange Circus #2" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Pete Collins</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">bass, keyboard, programming</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Pete Collins - Hawaii Worms" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Pete Collins</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">synths, programming, bass, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Pete Collins - Plunge" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Pete Collins</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">bass, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Pete Collins - Terminal Sunshine" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Pete Collins</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">bass, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Pete Collins - Wooly Mammoth" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Pete Collins</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">keyboards, programming, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Pierre - Zirkus" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Pierre</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">synths, machines, bass</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Robin Deacon - Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Robin Deacon</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Robin Deacon - The Yahoo's" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Robin Deacon</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">bass, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Simon Moran - Terminal Sunshine" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Simon Moran</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar, keyboard</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Stuart Hearn - The Attic" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Stuart Hearn</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Tim Morris - Chameleon Day" [margin=0, label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Tim Morris</TD></TR><TR><TD border="0" VALIGN="TOP"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">guitar, vocals</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]


# bands

"Rose Garden Sacrifice" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Rose Garden Sacrifice</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">(87)<br/>Goff rock</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"The Yahoo's" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">The Yahoo's</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">One rehearsal</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Nocturne" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Nocturne</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">(88 - 89)<br/>Goff rock</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Chameleon Day" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Chameleon Day</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">(89 - 90)<br/>One gig, melded Baggy<br/>with Loop-esque psych</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Terminal Sunshine" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Terminal Sunshine</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10"> </FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Eviva" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Eviva</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10"> </FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"A4 Notice" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">A4 Notice</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10"> </FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Plunge" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Plunge</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10"> </FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Flange Circus #1" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Flange Circus #1</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10"> </FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Flange Circus #2" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Flange Circus #2</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10"> </FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Probe" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Probe</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">(1991 - now)<br/>Ongoing intent to<br/>make electronic music</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Wooly Mammoth" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Wooly Mammoth</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10"> </FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Hawaii Worms" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Hawaii Worms</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10"> </FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Flange Circus #1" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Flange Circus #1</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10"> </FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Flange Circus #2" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Flange Circus #2</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10"> </FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">Cardiff Art School combo<br/>doing Nick Cave covers</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]

"The Attic" [bgcolor="yellow", margin=0, label=<<TABLE SIDES="B" PORT="bandport" BORDER="1" cellspacing="0"><TR><TD border="0">The Attic</TD><TD border="0"><FONT POINT-SIZE="10">allegedly seminal<br/>Bedford group</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>>]


# regular band links

"Eviva" -> "(various people) - Eviva""The Attic" -> "(various people) - The Attic""Zirkus" -> "ABB - Zirkus""Flange Circus #2" -> "Adam Clayton - Flange Circus #2""Chameleon Day" -> "Bon Holloway - Chameleon Day""Flange Circus #1" -> "Bon Holloway - Flange Circus #1""Flange Circus #2" -> "Bon Holloway - Flange Circus #2""Nocturne" -> "Bon Holloway - Nocturne""Rose Garden Sacrifice" -> "Bon Holloway - Rose Garden Sacrifice""Eviva" -> "Charles Freedman - Eviva""Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police" -> "Chris Gunningham - Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police""Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police" -> "Chris Jones - Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police""Wooly Mammoth" -> "Craig McIntosh - Wooly Mammoth""Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police" -> "Danny Tompkins - Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police""Chameleon Day" -> "Darren Hanson - Chameleon Day""Nocturne" -> "Darren Hanson - Nocturne""Rose Garden Sacrifice" -> "Darren Hanson - Rose Garden Sacrifice""Terminal Sunshine" -> "Dave Colbourne - Terminal Sunshine""The Attic" -> "Glenn ??? - The Attic""The Yahoo's" -> "Glenn ??? - The Yahoo's""Eviva" -> "Jamie Wire - Eviva""Chameleon Day" -> "Jay Stillwell - Chameleon Day""Nocturne" -> "Jay Stillwell - Nocturne""Rose Garden Sacrifice" -> "Jay Stillwell - Rose Garden Sacrifice""Flange Circus #1" -> "John Taylor - Flange Circus #1""Flange Circus #2" -> "John Taylor - Flange Circus #2""Nocturne" -> "Josh Saunders - Nocturne""Rose Garden Sacrifice" -> "Josh Saunders - Rose Garden Sacrifice""A4 Notice" -> "Martin Smith - A4 Notice""Wooly Mammoth" -> "Matthew Eades - Wooly Mammoth""Probe" -> "Matthew Petty - Probe""Plunge" -> "Nick Topp - Plunge""Plunge" -> "Paul Morgan - Plunge""Terminal Sunshine" -> "Paul Stevenson - Terminal Sunshine""A4 Notice" -> "Pete Collins - A4 Notice""Eviva" -> "Pete Collins - Eviva""Flange Circus #1" -> "Pete Collins - Flange Circus #1""Flange Circus #2" -> "Pete Collins - Flange Circus #2""Hawaii Worms" -> "Pete Collins - Hawaii Worms""Plunge" -> "Pete Collins - Plunge""Terminal Sunshine" -> "Pete Collins - Terminal Sunshine""Wooly Mammoth" -> "Pete Collins - Wooly Mammoth""Zirkus" -> "Pierre - Zirkus""Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police" -> "Robin Deacon - Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police""The Yahoo's" -> "Robin Deacon - The Yahoo's""Terminal Sunshine" -> "Simon Moran - Terminal Sunshine""The Attic" -> "Stuart Hearn - The Attic""Chameleon Day" -> "Tim Morris - Chameleon Day"
# more links

"Rose Garden Sacrifice" -> "Nocturne" [label="became"]"Nocturne" -> "Chameleon Day" [label=" "]"Pete Collins - Terminal Sunshine" -> "A4 Notice" [label="went on to form"]"Pete Collins - Terminal Sunshine" -> "Plunge" [label="went on to form"]"A4 Notice" -> "Plunge" [label="parallel project"]"Pete Collins - Plunge" -> "Eviva" [label=" "]"Pete Collins - Eviva" -> "Wooly Mammoth" [label=" "]"Pete Collins - Wooly Mammoth" -> "Hawaii Worms" [label="went on to form"]"Pete Collins - Hawaii Worms" -> "Flange Circus #1" [label="went on to form"]"Flange Circus #1" -> "Flange Circus #2" [label=" "]"Pete Collins - Flange Circus #2" -> "Zirkus" [label="parallel project"]"Bon Holloway - Flange Circus #2" -> "Zirkus" [label="parallel project"]"Robin Deacon - The Yahoo's" -> "Bobby Valentino and the Jazz Police" [label=" "]"Bon Holloway - Chameleon Day" -> "Flange Circus #1" [label=" "]
{ rank=same; "A4 Notice"; "Plunge"; }

}
```

Which gives this: [image: output from DOT file]

- Bands are HTML label nodes, with the name + a comment
- People are HTML label nodes, with the name + instrument or comment
- A person in a band is a unique record, because the same person might do different things in different bands.

Questions:

1. How can I automatically assign ranks so that bands don't appear in the same rank as people? (e.g. Nocturne)
2. How can I space nodes out horizontally?
3. I would prefer ortho splines, but they don't connect to the underside of the band node.
4. How do I make the edges touch the underside of the band nodes?
5. Is there an overall better way of doing this?

Comment: In general, you'll get better results here if you limit yourself to one specific question per question.  I have an answer for part of it, but if you ask too many questions you run the risk of the question being downvoted as "too broad."

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of questions for one question.  ;)  To answer #2, use the `nodesep` **attribute at the graph level** to widen the space between nodes.  The default value allows them to be quite close:

Reference: [GraphViz documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dnodesep).